# Internet Speeds going crazy (wi-fi only)?

Tags: router, wireless-router, internet-connection

[image]

This is a 60 second average sample of my wireless speeds as of two days ago (had to post link since I have <10 rep). I'm not a basic user, and I'm wondering why this would even happen. I fear the router may be giving out (on the wireless end and NOT the wired end), also there were a few power outages at this time, so I fear the router's wireless broadcaster may be on crutches due to a surge of some sort, it is NOT on a surge protector (which I do realize it really should be).

Things I've tried:

- Performed a Hard Reset on the router and re-building the network.

  - My SSID is not broadcast, the password to the router and the network are both fairly
    secure. (Non-sequential lowercase letters, uppercase letters, numbers, and symbols.)
  - I have changed the channel the router is using to almost all of the channels.
  - I've swapped DNS's just to make sure it's not my ISP.
  - Used a direct connection from the modem to ensure I'm actually getting the correct bandwidth.
  - Disabled/Re-enabled NAT.
  - Swapped out cables (since the cable from the modem to the router is actually a home-made CAT6       cable from a while back, had to make sure it wasn't my potentially shoddy work.)
- I've used the refresh button on the router countless times, and I've made sure my wireless receiver is still in working condition (as my computer is not the only one receiving poor speeds through wireless.)
- I've double-checked all settings (IP Address range, etc), checked the logs of the network, rebooted, and updated the firmware of the router.
- Last but not least, I have also reset power to both the modem and the router separately, at the same time, and the "picky way" that most ISP's have to tell you how (e.g. gotta do router, wait 5s, then modem, etc).

My Wireless Receiver:

- Rosewill USB Wireless Receiver (300mbps+300mbps)
- I am also on 64-bit Win8.1 (whereas my roommates are on Win8.1 and Win7, and my laptop on Win7)

My Router:

- Linksys E1200 Wireless Router

EDIT: I realize the graph is not always going to show what my throughput is, and only how much I'm using, but the screenshot in question was taken while I was downloading files from my Dropbox.

Comment: I'd do a site survey. I have no idea if its still free, but I used to use inssider on android to check if I was using a less popular channel

Comment: Honestly, if its none of that, then it's probably your ISP, I had the same thing with BT a while back and after MANY MANY phonecalls, they finally agreed that it was a line fault and sent out a technician to fix it, that is, if you're receiving dodgy internet connection when not on wireless too.

Comment: @YetiFiasco: I tested a direct connection straight from the modem and the bandwidth was at, if not a little higher, than what we were paying for. This was using both Charter's Speedtest (probably a bit biased), as well as Ookla's basic Speedtest. The time at which this drop is happening is irrelevent, though, due to it being consistent all hours of the day, and I'm not in a heavily crowded area.

Comment: It sounds like your wireless sender has begun to fail then, have you tried using a different router, and have you tested the wireless speed on other wireless devices? If it's just happening on your device, it could be a driver issue (as much as I hate to say it might be).

Comment: @YetiFiasco All devices (including mobile phones and any game consoles we could test it) are all plagued by what I'm afflicted with, so I hate to say it, but you may be right on the wireless sender failing.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution that the firmware on the router (that I did, in fact, *attempt* to update) was out of date even after I supposedly finished updating. It turns out after some interrogation from my roommates that one of them was fiddling with the router **while** I was updating, after I explicitly stated to not touch the router for a few minutes. After one final reset, I re-installed the latest firmware again (and this time barred off the router, heheh) and everything worked out fine. Thank you everyone for your help!

Comment: Horray! Once again a problem caused by persons unknown doing things they shouldn't! IT Support should be renamed "people herding".

Answer (score 1):

The steps you have already carried out seem to point to it being the wireless part of the router itself (*thanks for doing these by the way, makes diagnostics much easier!*).

As you have stated it might have been victim of a power surge and that all devices are receiving the same poor wireless performance, the likelihood is that the wireless sender or any number of components that work with it have been **damaged**. I would suggest borrowing or purchasing a new wireless router and see if the issue persists. You may have luck finding the damaged component if you're a dab hand with a multi-metre and a soldering iron.

If the issue still persists, contact your local place of worship and enquire about an exorcism or purification, as you may have an infestation of wireless poltergeists.

Answer (score 0):

A really weird answer, but this worked for me when I had no clue what was causing low wifi speeds, even when I was very, very close to our router (Netgear 802.11n).

I had change the maximum operating speed from 300Mbps to 150Mbps (since I got only 90Mbps from my ISP, I didn't care).
If I set the TLS limit on 150Mbps max, I got a very stable connection around 50Mbps.
If I set the TLS limit on 300Mbps max, I got a terrifying not stable connection around 10/20Mbps.

I still don't understand why that would work, but if you changed these settings, you could try this.

Sorry I had to post this as 'answer', but since I'm new to this forum, I can not publish a comment (50rep needed, I got only 16rep atm).

Comment: I had attempted to look through the Linksys UI to find what you were talking about and was unable to. I think that is a Netgear-specific thing. But thank you for your help, regardless!

Comment: I meant this mode:
![link](http://i.imgur.com/s9zzSVk.png)
I think its not Netgear-specific, but it could be that your router doesn't allow you to change the speed for this mode. However, if u can't change this mode, or can't find where to do it, this probably isn't causing the problem (since you haven't changed it recently).

Comment: Yes that mode is unavailable to my current router, but may be implemented in other non-Netgear routers. Thank you for your suggestions. :)